# Calendar component with add/edit/delete title option in angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

I need calendar component where on click on day block, I need to add/edit title

Does anyone know about such a Calendar component in angular?

Answer (score 2):

have you tried [angular-calendar](https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-calendar/#/kitchen-sink)?

You can find the repo in [here](https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-calendar)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Angular bootstrap module to install all required functionality including Accordion, Alert, Buttons, Carousel, Collapse, Datepicker, Dropdown, Modal, Pagination, Popover, Progressbar, Rating, Tabs, Timepicker, Tooltip, Typeahead etc..

Please visit: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io